# docker-registry v2.2.0 S3 config not overwritten

Tags: amazon-s3, docker, docker-registry

I'm having an issue trying to start a docker registry service with S3 backend. Its acting very strangely. If I launch like this:

```
docker run -d -e SETTINGS_FLAVOR=s3 -e AWS_BUCKET=sotic-docker-registry -e STORAGE_PATH=/registry -e AWS_REGION=eu-west-1 -e AWS_KEY=***** -e AWS_SECRET=***** -e STORAGE_REDIRECT=true -e SEARCH_BACKEND=sqlalchemy -p 5000:5000 registry:2.2.0
```

As suggested by other topics on here, I don’t get an overridden config file.

Running docker exec on the container and looking at the /etc/docker/registry/config.yml seems to suggest I'm still using the local storage.

```
root@5727b353e734:/# vi /etc/docker/registry/config.yml

version: 0.1
log:
  fields:
    service: registry
storage:
    cache:
        blobdescriptor: inmemory
    filesystem:
        rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
http:
    addr: :5000
    headers:
        X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
health:
  storagedriver:
    enabled: true
    interval: 10s
    threshold: 3
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the /etc/docker/registry/config.json file never gets touched in the default image. None of the overrides seem to work.

The answer is to build your own registry image and ADD a config.json with the required components in it.

Ric